# I escaped Rotom battle in Lost Hotel, can I try to catch him one more time?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I've leveled my Pokes for some time (couple hours) and I noticed place I haven't seen before. I encountered Rotom and When I wanted to transorm into Mega evolution I clicked "run". Can I go back to catch rotom one more time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes** -- more than one rotom will spawn, although they will always be in shaking trash cans. If you don't see any, try leaving and re-entering the area. In addition, they will only appear there on Tuesdays.

Comment: Not only that - only four of the trash cans are relevant. The one to the left of the Punk Couple is "daily", and can not contain a Rotom, while the four trashcans to the right are "Tuesday trashcans" and are able to contain a Rotom.